# Sql query returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM class c 
Left join sub_inclass s on s.class_id=c.class_id 
join subject sb on  s.sub_id=sb.sub_id
```

The other two except class 'table' are empty, I have left join but class table is still not displaying

Comment: should be an outer join

Answer (score 3):

If you use only `join` it is an `inner join` by default.

```
SELECT * FROM class c 
Left join sub_inclass s on s.class_id=c.class_id 
left join subject sb on  s.sub_id=sb.sub_id
 ^-------------------you missed left here
```

Comment: I want the class table in every case so i have used left join there only, Is it necessary to write left join in the second place too?

Comment: You are using the `class` table as basis. And every table you join need to be `left join`ed in order to prevent filtering records of `class`.